# How to implement javascript into an html page

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I would like to implement this script into a html page :

```js
function rcirc(x, y, m, b) {
  let m2 = -1 / m;
  let b2 = y - (m * x);
  let y2 = (b2 - b) / (m - m2);
  let x2 = (y2 - b) / m;
  return [x2, y2];
}

var x = window.prompt("enter the x value: ");
var y = window.prompt("enter the y value: ");
var m = window.prompt("enter the m value: ");
var b = window.prompt("enter the b value: ");
let point = rcirc(x, y, m, b);

alert(point);
```

I tried adding `<script></script>` around the code but it does not work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to _run_ this code in an HTML page? You can't _convert_ to HTML. (The code works btw, as you can see from the snippet I made.)

Comment: It's not clear at all what do you actually want.

Comment: "but it does not work" what does this actually mean? it's too vague to be able to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Hoadi here is a working example of your code implemented into an html "website".
The html renders after you clicked away the final alert.

```html
<hml>
    <body>
        <h1>some stuff...</h1>
    </body>
    <script>
function rcirc(x, y, m, b) {
    let m2 = -1/m;
    let b2 = y - (m * x);
    let y2 = (b2 - b) / (m - m2);
    let x2 = (y2 - b) / m;
    return [x2, y2];
  }

  var x = window.prompt("enter the x value: ");
  var y = window.prompt("enter the y value: ");
  var m = window.prompt("enter the m value: ");
  var b = window.prompt("enter the b value: ");
  let point = rcirc(x, y, m, b);
  alert(point);
</script>
</hml>
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi Hoadi I see your new. If  you found  my answer useful then you vote it up or approve it.